# UIPopoverController not dismissed automatically when pressing outside

Tags: storyboard, uinavigationbar, toolbar, uipopovercontroller, dismiss

I needed three buttons in the top left spot of an iPad navbar. From another post here, I received the suggestion to put a toolbar there, since the navbar only allows one left bar item. Now there are three buttons (Create, Reorder, Delete), each opening another popover.

The bad thing is that tapping inside the toolbar does not close any popup. If I tap inside the visible part of the navbar, and anywhere below (outside the popover), the popover disappears. But when I tap on the remaining area of the toolbar which is placed above the navbar (which should be wider than the English buttons require, due to translation), the popover does not disappear. Worse, if I tap on any of the buttons, its popover appears, overlaid over the existing one. I can even stack the same popover.

I could imagine a way to stop overlaying popovers (before displaying a new one, check for an old one), but what about taps in the empty region of the toolbar?

Any help greatly appreciated - including additional tips how to add three buttons to the left half of a navigation bar.

Regards, nobi

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578117/uipopovercontroller-not-dismissed-when-opened-from-self-navigationitem-inside-u) for a similar question with a solution idea. Seems to be an area that needs manual implementation work.

Comment: Finally, a solution can be found here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578117/uipopovercontroller-not-dismissed-when-opened-from-self-navigationitem-inside-u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, a solution can be found here:

[UIPopoverController not dismissed when opened from self.navigationItem (inside UINavigationController)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578117/uipopovercontroller-not-dismissed-when-opened-from-self-navigationitem-inside-u)

The trick is to set the `passThroughViews` of the `UIPopoverController` to `nil`.